# Inline method as a build step

Tags: c#, security, obfuscation

I have a method that checks the license in our application. I would like to inline this method during build (or after) to increase the complexity of hacking the license. Basically I want something to take the code in this method, walk through all the usages, and substitute them to the copies of the code - then remove all the usages and the method itself. This is very similar to what Resharper does on `Ctrl+Alt+N Inline method`:[image]

But rather as a build step. Is it possible somehow?

I've looked at `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]` attribute, but this is not what I want. It affects only the compiled code after JIT, but I would like to do this for generated IL.

I will also use obfuscator after this.